# What happens to VRAM when program exits unexpectedly

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

Say I have loaded a texture or two and maybe a some shaders, a VAO, a VBO, and I run the program.

Say that the program hits some sort of runtime error and terminates before all of those buffer objects and textures can be deleted.

Are they stuck in video memory until I restart my computer?

I know that java does its own cleanup, but I don't think opengl does, so I'm curious what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are they stuck in video memory until I restart my computer?

No. The graphics card is managed by the graphics driver which notices, or gets informed that a process holding handled to it has terminated. All resources associated with a process and not being used by other processes will be freed.

On some OS it is possible to share a OpenGL context between processes. Those will of course stay around if one of the processes terminated.

---

BTW: OpenGL does not use the term "video memory". There's *fast* and *slow* memory, but depending on the implementation they may be the same. Also when you upload a texture a copy of it will be held in system memory as well, as OpenGL doesn't impose memory constraints on textures and buffer objects. It will swap out data to make room for required resources if neccessary.

Comment: Thanks.  That clears it up for me.  Just out of curiosity, though:  Why is it common practice, then, to go through and clean up all your resources at close if the driver usually just does it for you?

Comment: @SirYancy: The main reason for this is the same as why to clean up your program's resources at exit: It makes debugging easier. If you don't clean up yourself memory debuggers both for CPU and GPU resources will report memory leaks. For short lived programs this is no problem. But usually a program will run for a longer amount of time (like a game) and the code that does the cleanup at exit is usually the very same code that also cleans up unused resources during program execution to free up memory for other stuff. In a game for example this is crucial.

Comment: That...makes a hell of a lot of sense.  Thank you.